# How to wait for the backend in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm testing a web page where the user can send a message to another via a textinput. A POST request is then send on the server and the message is dumped on the disk in the `var/mail/new` folder.

After automatising the sending of the message in the page with Protractor I'm calling `browser.waitForAngular()` and `browser.driver.sleep(4000)` to leave time for the backend to write the mail on the disk.

After these calls the check of the email's presence fails. When looking in the Unix shell, I can confirm that the email was sent and also the next test marked with in Jasmine with `it` confirms the presence of the email.

Why is `browser.driver.sleep(4000)` not effective to wait for the backend to proceed? How can I correct the following code?

```
it("is possible to send a message", function() {
    shared.loginContributor();

    var mailsBeforeMessaging =
        fs.readdirSync(browser.params.mail.queue_path + "/new");
    console.log('mailsBeforeMessaging');
    console.log(mailsBeforeMessaging.length);
    console.log(fs.lstatSync(browser.params.mail.queue_path + "/new"));

    var usersListing = new UserPages.UsersListing().get();
    var annotatorPage = usersListing.getUserPage("annotator");

    annotatorPage.sendMessage("title5", "content64");

    exec("/tmp/check.sh");

    // we expect the message widget to disappear
    var button = element(by.css(".user-profile-info-button"));
    console.log('waiting');
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button), 5000);
    console.log('waiting is finished');
    expect(EC.elementToBeClickable(button)).toBeTruthy();

    // wait for mail to be dumped on the disk?
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.driver.sleep(4000);

    exec("/tmp/check.sh");

    var mailsAfterMessaging =
        fs.readdirSync(browser.params.mail.queue_path + "/new");
    console.log('mailsAfterMessaging');
    // ERROR: here the number of emails is NOT incremented
    console.log(mailsAfterMessaging.length);
    console.log(fs.lstatSync(browser.params.mail.queue_path + "/new"));
});

it("xyz", function() {

    console.log(fs.lstatSync(browser.params.mail.queue_path + "/new"));
    // here the number of emails is incremented
    var mailsAfterMessaging =
        fs.readdirSync(browser.params.mail.queue_path + "/new");
    console.log('mailsAfterMessaging');
    console.log(mailsAfterMessaging.length);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the Protractor functions do not *do* anything.  They queue something up to be done *later*, and return promise to do it.  After an `it` block schedules a bunch of things to do, they actually start happening (via the promises they registered in the ControlFlow).

Your checks, however, are all executing immediately.  So, they are happening before any of the protractor calls accomplish anything.

Use `then` to make the waiting and dependencies explicit in your test.  Like this:

```
annotatorPage.sendMessage("title5", "content64").then(function() {
    exec("/tmp/check.sh");
});
```

or:

```
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(button), 5000).then(function() {
   console.log('wait-for-clickable has completed'); // B
});
console.log('wait-for-clickable has been scheduled'); // A
```

See the [Protractor Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) documentation and the [Webdriver JS API doc](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Understanding_the_API).

Its not you.  This is a crazy API to learn because it does not act at all like anyone familiar with normal synchronous programming would expect.

Comment: Thank you for your friendly and detailed answer. Is there any way to empty the queue before executing the test and avoid the call to ``then``?

Comment: Note for a future me: It is possible to control the flow with ``browser.controlFlow()`` and ``flow.execute``.