# Promises callbacks ordering in Protractor

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

In the following code why is `promise resolved` displayed before `promise being resolved`?

```
    var p = protractor.promise.defer();

    element(by.css("input.m-call-to-action")).click().then(function() {
        console.log('promise being resolved');
        p.fulfill(true);
    });

    browser.wait(function() {
        console.log('p', p);
        return p;
    }, 5000);

    console.log('promise resolved', p);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for the backend in Protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808137/how-to-wait-for-the-backend-in-protractor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically what [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow) documentation page is describing:

> WebDriverJS (and thus, Protractor) APIs are entirely asynchronous. All
>   functions return promises.

Protractor maintains a control flow queue where your `click()` promise is at the beginning and `browser.wait()` is at the end. When `promise resolved` is logged none of the promises in the queue are resolved.

Comment: Why putting expect(true).toBeTruthy(); before the last console.log does not force both wait and the then to be executed before the last log?

Comment: @z1naOK9nu8iY5A is the behavior consistent? `expect`, btw, is "patched" to resolve a promise also.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve all promises and their callbacks before calling ``console.log('promise resolved', p);`` ?

Comment: @z1naOK9nu8iY5A yup, using `q.all()` or `protractor.promise.all()`, see examples at https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/639, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21736757/771848.